# How to respond immediately?

Tags: node.js

I am working with `NodeJS + Server-Side-Rendering`.  So, while the HTML is *rendering*, instead of making the client wait on a blank screen, I would like to render this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>PageTitle</title></head>
  <body><h1>Loading....</h1></body>
</html>
```

And, once the `server-side` is **ready** with the `html`, I want to `stream` it to the client.  Basically, I would like to replace the `html` mentioned above with the `html` that has been `created/rendered`...

Could I do something with `NodeJS streams`?

Answer (score 1):

I would say it might be possible, but I would discourage it as a solution to fast rendering.  Instead, render the whole page on the server, and cache the DOM in memory.  That way when a request comes in, you can respond instantly with the cached copy and deliver the whole content without a loading screen.

Alternatively, I would use javascript to fetch the content from the node server, after page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am greatly misinformed, there is no way you are going to be able to do this using purely server side rendering techniques.  You get a single response from the server that renders your:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>PageTitle</title></head>
  <body><h1>Loading....</h1></body>
</html>
```

You'll need to add another technology into the mix to get additional responses fron the server. Ajax calls to the server, websockets, webworkers, etc.